# Show SQLite data in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to show data from `SQLite` in `listview`.

There's no error on my code but I got this as a result

[image]

Here's my code.

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
    List<AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();

    allItems = db.getAllAccommodations();       

    for (AllItem cn : allItems) {
        String log = "Table Id: "+cn.getTableID()+",Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getCategory_name() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getItem_name();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allItems);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How to get the real data from `SQLite` ?

Thanks before :D

Comment: are you check what you insert in database?

Comment: Please check what data u inserted and also check what data in arraylist

Comment: I think you need to make it generic: `ArrayAdapter<AllItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AllItem>(...)`

Comment: Of course. And I already insert it at `MainActivity` class

Comment: don't use ArrayAdapter,  use SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: @pskink i'm trying using `SimpleCursorAdapter` but its already `deprecated`.

Comment: @Matthew only one ctor is deprecated,  try one with int flags

Comment: @pskink what is ctor mean?

Comment: @Matthew c(onstruc)tor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ArrayAdapter with custom object your result is what `AllItem.toString()` returns. for custom objects you need to create your own implementation of ArrayAdapter or simple Adapter check this tutorial [Reference](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

What you can do if you don't want to create your own adapter, you can override `toString()` method of your AllItem class and return required text you can try to format it. but you may need to extend adapter and create custom cell layouts.